# Can wallpaper be coated with a protective finish?

Tags: polyurethane, wallpaper, finish

I want to use wallpaper as the decorative top to some nightstands I plan on making. The wallpaper by itself would probably not last too long especially with cups/glasses being set on them frequently. My idea is to just coat the wallpaper with a protective finish like a spray-on lacquer or polyurethane. Will this ruin the wallpaper or is this a suitable method to protect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, yes - you can help protect the wallpaper with polyurethane. However, once the paper is on, it's not coming off without a complete overhaul (sand it all off and redo it), and you should be aware that paper tends to fade and yellow after a while.

Also, if you use a brush to apply water based poly then you need to apply it kind of quickly and be (kind of) gentle because wet paper is easily marred.

Oil based urethane should be easier to use (provided the ink doesn't bleed). You should test some paper separately (perhaps test your method on a cardboard box) before applying it to the nightstand.

Comment: It might even be worth having a piece of glass cut (and tempered if cost allows). Then you could change underneath as need of whim suited. This is also nice as it is a mechanical barrier to the surface that is easily cleaned and replaced.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk Yes, that's a fine idea. As a side note (or another alternative) I have used paper on stiff cardboard to make panels to cover wooden boxes. This actually held up well, but it was not being kicked around or handled much. I don't think cardboard panels would be good for a night stand, but I thought it might be worth mentioning for other similar projects and since it also makes redecorating simple.

Comment: I go along with the idea of the tempered plate glass top on the night stands to cover the decorative paper. The top of the stand could even be made with a trim around the top edge in such manner that it captures the glass top and keep it from moving around on the top of the table.

Answer (score 1):

There is a product designed for decoupage projects called Mod Podge that is sold at many arts and crafts stores which will seal the paper, and protect it. However it would not be durable enough to just use that, so it would have to be sealed with an additional layer of either polyurethane, shellac, or lacquer.

Practice applying the products on some scrap pieces, and experiment with what works the best. I have not tried this personally, but I believe that the paper can be coated with a few very light coats of Mod Podge first. Only apply enough to barely cover the surface of the paper, and don't reapply it until it is fully dry because it may not fully cure and be too sticky. The Mod Podge is only to protect the inks in the paper from bleeding, and is not meant as a final finish.

After the first coats are dry, then I would switch to a sealer. I prefer using lacquer because the finish is stable, durable, and will not peel over time like polyurethane. Apply a few light coats, and allow to dry. The best part about lacquer is that it drys very quickly, and you can apply several coats in a single day. Poly and even shellac take quite a bit longer to cure. You can lightly buff out the eggshell finish of the lacquer using extra fine steel wool. Be sure to wipe the object free of dust before applying more layers. The trick to lacquer is that you need to apply several thin layers for the best effect. 10 or 15 coats is not uncommon. Another thing you may want to do is use a high gloss lacquer for the majority of the coats, and then using a lacquer with a satin finish for the final coat. This will ensure that you will get the best clarity out of the finish. If it is done properly, then you wouldn't even be able to tell that there is a finish on it until you feel it.

Comment: I found out that they have an outdoor version of Mod Podge that is water resistant. This may be what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Hooplehead24 I'm familiar with mod podge... it's essentially watered down elemers glue (priced like a craft supply). Here's how you can [make decoupage glue from regular glue](http://www.themakeyourownzone.com/2013/02/make-your-own-mod-podge-for-decoupage-crafts.html). But I definitely wouldn't set my glass on it (even after it's dry) or else you'll probably end up having it glued to the nightstand!

Comment: @BenWelborn oh that's interesting. Thanks for the tip. What is different about the outdoor version? It does say it's water resistant. I wonder if that wouldn't have the issue of a glass getting glued to it.

Comment: @Hooplehead24 The outdoor mod podge is acrylic resin diluted approximately 20 fold? compared with exterior paint (based this estimation from the VOC content). I'm afraid I'm not totally certain about that dilution. But it's acrylic, like exterior paint. The interior stuff is polyvinyl acetate (PVA). Modern school craft glue is about 50% PVA, and most directions for making decoupage dilute school glue 1:1 with water.